# Hot cups and dishes

Tags: warming

New combo micro covection not useful to warm my coffee as the cups get burning hot. They do not get hot in my regular microwave

Comment: Is there a setting to use it as microwave-only ?

Answer (score 1):

The convection (and grill, if you have it) modes use heating elements similar to those in your regular oven.  The convection fan does not blow the microwaves around; rather, it circulates the heated air.  So heating your coffee in convection mode is the same as heating it in your regular oven, only faster due to the microwaves.

As Joe implies above, you want to ensure that you're in microwave only mode.  Your manual should tell you how.